# difference in conversion between spring and spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I would like to understand why the format of the output is different for the same code in Spring vs Spring Boot.

```
import java.util.Date;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@EnableWebMvc
public class Myspring {
     @GetMapping(path="/oops")
     public @ResponseBody Date oops () {
           return new Date();
     }
}
```

without spring boot:
curl http://localhost:8080/oops
1625506637687

with spring boot:
curl http://localhost:8080/oops
"2021-07-05T18:22:43.364+00:00"

and how would I go about making the format of the output of plain Spring the same as Spring Boot?

Comment: I suspect the response is being written as json. Spring Boot configured Jackson to disable the writing of dates as timestamps: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.x/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper

Comment: yeah that was it, what threw me off was spring was ignoring spring.jackson.serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps=false in application.properties.

Comment: As I've stated on the duplicate issue you've raised (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27152), `application.properties` is not considered at all by Spring Framework, this is a Spring Boot feature.